# Getting nginx environment variable in laravel with cached config

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, config

I use laravel framework on 2 websites,
The application backend is one, but view paths is different for each site.
There is nginx variable "WEBSITE", which is available in PHP (phpinfo prints it).
When I run application locally, all is right. But in production, I get exception what variable is not exists.

I discovered what during deploy running command php artisan config:cache, which cached all config in "bootstrap" directory. I don't may delete this command, because it ups performance of site. This command caches all config including app/config/view.php file that descript changes in view paths, like this

```
'paths' => [
    resource_path('views/' . env('WEBSITE')),
],
```

but config already cached without variable and in this form is delivered to the production.
I don't understand how fix this problem, other that edit all views, base layouts for both sites. Does anyone know how to solve this problem in a simple way?

Comment: You won't be able to use config caching if your config values are dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a fallback by explicitly adding WEBSITE=somewebsiteurl in your production sites .env, then re-cache the config and try if it works.